# What to write in bucket policy for secure my video

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I hosted my video on Amazon S3 for selling online course like Udemy.
Can you guide me about, what bucket policy do I need for secure my video that student can view them but don't download or someone else can't find URL for that video.  What should I write in the bucket policy? And which player do I need on my wordpress website to play these videos.Please help me out.

```html
{
 "Version": "2008-10-17",
 "Id": "Policy1414368633278",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "Stmt1414368595009",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": "*"
   },
   "Action": "s3:GetObject",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKETNAME/*",
   "Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
     "aws:Referer": "http://YOURDOMAINNAME.com/*"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code describing what you have done so far.

Comment: {
 "Version": "2008-10-17",
 "Id": "Policy1414368633278",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "Stmt1414368595009",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": "*"
   },
   "Action": "s3:GetObject",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKETNAME/*",
   "Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
     "aws:Referer": "http://YOURDOMAINNAME.com/*"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}

Answer (score 1):

A bucket policy alone is not sufficient to secure your content as you describe.

You will require some application logic to determine whether a user is permitted to access the object. If the application then wishes to grant access, it can create a time-limited [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). This allows the object to be accessed for a specific time period, after which access is denied.

Companies like Udemy implement their own form of access control. If you were to supply a video to them, they would host it and control access.

**Bottom line:** You need an application to control access, which then provides a link that tells Amazon S3 to grant access to the object.

Comment: Thanks, John for your great support!